# Find last row in each category

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using `Sybase` which doesn't support a lot of cool functions that people use here. So, please keep that in mind while helping me.

I have a db which looks something like this:

```
Type         RowTime             Quantity        
cat1  1      10:01:01.000        50          
cat1  2      10:01.01.001        0          
cat1  3      10:01:01.002        1000          
cat1  4      10:01.01.003        100          
cat1  5      10:01:03.001        100
```

Except there are *cat2, cat3, cat4, etc* as well.

I want to find the extract the last row from each *category* based on time arranged in *`ascending order`*. So, for the given table above I want to extract `row 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking a look at sybase documentation it seems like you have a rank function.  So here's a stab at it:

```
declare @table table ( tp varchar(30), rowtime datetime, quantity int) 

insert @table select 'cat1 1', '20120101', 50
insert @table select 'cat2 1', '20130101', 50
insert @table select 'cat3 1', '20110101', 50
insert @table select 'cat4 1', '20100101', 50
insert @table select 'cat5 1', '20090101', 50
select * from (
   select *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  RowTime DESC) AS Rank from @table 
) a
where [RANK]=1
```

Got the rank function from here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00169.1270/html/iqperf/CEGDJFCE.htm

Comment: @user1949158 There are two answers here.. so you can run both and see which one works, if both works then you check on the `explain` plan... :)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Type, MAX(Time) MaxTime
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Type) B
    ON A.Type = B.Type AND A.Time = B.MaxTime
```

Comment: My table is massive, is this the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM  table_name
GROUP BY Type
HAVING RowTime = max(RowTime)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Oracle queries that may give you some ideas. I'm not sure if these analytic functions available in Sybase. Basically you need to partition your query by category then get the last row in that categody - probably MAX(row_time) in your case. Many analytic functions may be used for this: ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK()...

```
-- Selects sal within dept with Rank = 2 --
SELECT ename, sal, sal_rank
  FROM ( SELECT ename, sal, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal ASC) sal_rank FROM scott.emp ) 
WHERE sal_rank <= 2
/

-- MIN/MAX sal in each dept --
SELECT empno, deptno, sal,
   MIN(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) "Lowest",
   MAX(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) "Highest"
 FROM scott.emp
ORDER BY deptno, sal
/
```